# searching music file in a computer

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins

I am making a web site and I want to search and filter all the music and play it in my player.

Is it possible?  I need help and some ideas.

Thank you!!

Comment: we need way more information to help you in any sort. What kind of operating system? Which music player? That at least!

Comment: @chris lively: yes i want to search music...

Comment: @alfred: the flow for this is...i make a music web and every time a user use my site i want that i can search all the music in the pc they use and play it in jwplayer....

Comment: @jeroen: music files.. but not in the server...a music that was in the store in the pc that the user used...

Comment: the music in the users pc? That is going to be very hard(impossible?) using PHP only. PHP does not have permission(security off course) to access the files on users disc.

Comment: @user595029: Without using something like ActiveX, this isn't possible.

Comment: @alfred: not only php...but i don't know what other language should i use...is there any idea?..i really need for help..

Comment: @Chris I guess he could use activeX(dislike it(activeX is unsafe)), but then only the users using internet explorer can use his website.

Comment: @user595029 I think this problem is over your(my) head(difficult). It can be done using other languages like for example Java, but it can't be done using only a server-side language.

Comment: @alfred: ah!...thanks alfred..is there's a way that java can be connect to the web?..

Comment: Not only impossible without ActiveX or similar on the user's PC, but also potentially criminal. I have music files on my PC that are legitimate for my own use... if they're accessed by a remote machine though, so that you can play them on your player, then that's a DRM violation.

Comment: @mark: i don't need to remote the machine only to get the music files..."all the music on a user's PC won't save on the database it just play in the in the my player "...

Comment: @user595029: Having read most of your comments, I understand what it is your after however I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how the web works.  Your first step should be to either find someone that knows how web sites work or to get a book and start reading.

Comment: @chris: i already know the fundamental on how the web works..but my concern is about the an non-online application and online application. is there a possible way that they can communicate to each other...that's really the point of my concern...

Comment: @user595029: Respectfully, if you did understand then you'd know why this won't work.  A website does not have access to a local users files without EXPLICIT permissions.  There are huge security reasons for this.  Even then you have to use a technology like ActiveX which will throw all sorts of warnings to the user about how this is a very bad idea.  If this is supposed to go out to the general public, the odds of anyone allowing you that type of control over their machine approaches nil pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a process looking for all files in a directory, and with this library "[getid3](http://getid3.sourceforge.net/)" in PHP. storing the data in a database, and then do a simple search with PHP in the database for what you want.

**EDIT**

In case you want to access the user's PC, only you can with tools such as [HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in IE or Chrome extensions with the [permission](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/manifest.html#permissions) of the user.

Comment: if I understand correctly he does not want to search music on his server, but on the user's computer.

Comment: @Alfred ok, as he put "i make the music", I assumed he was looking at his pc and not on the user's PC.

Comment: alfred was right i won't search music on server...and one thing i won't save music files on my server because it cause the page to load very slow...